# Remove all lines which do not contain a period

Tags: windows, batch-file, pattern-matching, substring

I have a text like this in `%userprofile%\i.txt`:

```
PDF

wikkipedia.ord
notavalidURL
snapfish.com
.tunnelbear.com
mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
```

I want to convert it to a string like this:

```
wikkipedia.ord snapfish.com .tunnelbear.com mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox!
```

I want to do this using native cmd.exe syntax only (no powershell, cygwin, etc.).

So I know that I can do this:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set row=
    for /f %%x in (%userprofile%\i.txt) do set "row=!row!%%x"
    echo %row% >%userprofile%\o.txt
    echo %row%
```

How can my result ignore all substrings which do not contain at least one period character?

this will delete the contents of the file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=
@For /F "EOL=|Tokens=*" %%x In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "."^<"%userprofile%\i.txt"^"') Do @Set "row=!row!%%x"
echo %row% >%userprofile%\o.txt
echo %row%
```

where as this will join all lines leaving no whitespaces between the sub-strings:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=
@For /F "EOL=|Tokens=*" %%x In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "."^<"%userprofile%\i.txt"^"') Do @Set "row=!row!%%x"
echo %row% >%userprofile%\o.txt
echo %row%
```

but i need white-spaces between all those substring being put out.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=                                         
@For /F "EOL=|Tokens=*" %%x In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "."^<"%userprofile%\i.txt"^"') Do @Set "row=!row! %%x"
echo %row% >%userprofile%\o.txt
echo %row%
```

this is a lot better but i have white-spaces left over from the strings that were removed.

[image]

i need the output to separate the remaining strings but not clutter the file with random white-spaces.
this way i will be able to pass " " as a parameter for a StringSplit() or something like that.

this is the difference between 'Tokens=*' in the code and 'Tokens=*' taken out:

[image]

Comment: Just use the built-in `find.exe`: `@For /F "EOL=|Tokens=*" %%# In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "."^<"test.txt"^"')Do @Set ...`

Comment: ...and obviously if your batch file isn't running with `%userprofile%\desktop` as the current directory, use the full or relative path to `test.txt` as necessary, e.g. `@For /F "EOL=|Tokens=*" %%# In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "."^<"%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt"^"')Do @Set ...`

Comment: Why are you complaining that there's no space, but not making any attempt to add them? e.g. `Do @Set "row=!row! %%x"` or `Do @Set "row=!row!%%x "` or `Do @Set "row= !row!%%x"`.

Comment: Try to remember to use quote if you go work with some kind of variable where it contents path, like this one: **`%path_to_some_folde_that_have_space_in_name%`** , because this, @compo have written to you: **`^<"%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt"^`**

Comment: Also, don't try to read the content of a file and overwrite to the same file at the same time. I would advise you to write to a file with a different extension, then `Rename` it afterwards, or to write it to a directory you aren't parsing, then `Move` it to the original location with the /Y` overwrite option afterwards instead.

Comment: I haven't attemped your task, I've made comments with code to replace some of yours. If I was attempting to answer your entire question, I'd have posted in the answer area, with a full code solution. Can you please update your question to provide your up to date code, the before and after `.txt` file contents and an explanation of the issue you're facing.

Comment: Your edit leads me to assume that your batch file is where your issue lies. Please take a look at line `3` of your code to see if you've `set row=<a bunch of space characters>`, that line should read `Set "row="`.

Comment: Also, as your text file contents don't contain any visible space characters you may be better advised to remove `Tokens=*`.

Comment: @Compo your last comment addresses a more serious issue with my code. with out your fix my code allows for entire sentences to be retained (as they tend to end with a period.) but now those sentences are reduced to the first word in the sentence. How can i get rid of those strings as well? i only want single words that have periods (beginning, ending, or float)?

Comment: Well your example file suggests that none of your strings have space characters, and in fact any valid URL would use `%20` instead of a space character. Now there seems to be additional content you haven't previously mentioned. You cannot suddenly change something after I've solved your issue and expect it to still be a valid solution.

Comment: @Compo you answered my question and many more a long time ago. But instead of posting an answer and moving on you are helping me. and i'm grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already provided in the comments sufficient information for you to correct your original methodology complete with the `Find` command.

However, given your example file content and stated intention, this may be sufficient for your needs:

```bat
@((For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%# In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "."^<"%UserProfile%\i.txt"^"')Do @Set /P "=%%# "<NUL)&Echo()>"%UserProfile%\o.txt"
```

Comment: is this missing a ')' ? i'm getting 'ECHO is off' typed out and saved in o.txt

Comment: You have obviously not used the code exactly as I've provided it, with the `%userprofile%\i.txt` content at the top of your question. You should get the following content in `%userprofile%\o.txt`, `wikkipedia.ord snapfish.com .tunnelbear.com mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox `.