# joining lines while adding white-spaces to select strings in CMD is not working

Tags: string, batch-file, join, replace, whitespace

my test string is:

```
this is a sentence.
google.com

here is another sentence.
microsoft.com
this sentence has no period
```

my code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set row=
@((For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%# In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "."^<"%UserProfile%\i.txt"^"')Do @Set /P "=%%# "<NUL)&Echo()>"%UserProfile%\o.txt"
echo %row% >%userprofile%\o.txt
echo %row%
C:\Users\qwerp>joint3
ECHO is off.
```

i was expecting to get:

```
google.com microsoft.com
```

instead i got:

```
ECHO is off.
```

what am i doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: @Compo is this not what you had in mind?

Comment: The line after the `for` loop should probably be `set /p "row="<%userprofile%\o.txt` ("Read the text file generated by the `for` loop into a variable") instead of `echo %row% >...` ("Write the (empty) variable to the file, overwriting it's previous content")

Comment: No, @Elisha, most especially because the single line of code I provided for you in my previous answer was the entire batch file, you've added lines above and below it for absolutely no reason. As for your changed parameters, you can simply replace `find.exe` with `findstr.exe`, obviously changing the match option(s) accordingly. Please see my answer below for the complete script incorporating that change.

Comment: This is a follow-up of the thread [Remove all lines which do not contain a period](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59567496), correct?

Comment: @aschipfl not quite. this a new question that arose in a thread. but since the answer to my first question is in the thread (and not in the posted answer) and the answer to my new question what arose in the thread (which is the posted answer) is not the answer to the original question is saw it unfair to arbitrate the new question in the same thread. here the answer to my new question is clarified to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example file content change and the stated intention, this may be sufficient for your needs, simply changing `find.exe` to `findstr.exe`, *(with appropriate options)*:

```bat
@((For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %%# In ('^""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "\." "%UserProfile%\i.txt"^|"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "[^\.]$"^"')Do @Set /P "=%%# "<NUL)&Echo()>"%UserProfile%\o.txt"
```